# An error: TimeoutExpired: Command occurred while using auto py to exe with python3.10

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe

i recently updated from python3.7 to python3.10 and now when i try to convert my script to exe using auto-py-to-exe i get the following error:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.13.0
Building directory: C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/background.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img_textBox0.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img_textBox1.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img0.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img1.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img2.png;." --add-data "D:/classes/python/python/img3.png;."  "D:/classes/python/python/RBZapp.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data D:/classes/python/python/background.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img_textBox0.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img_textBox1.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img0.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img1.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img2.png;. --add-data D:/classes/python/python/img3.png;. D:/classes/python/python/RBZapp.py --distpath C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1\application --workpath C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1\build --specpath C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1

507609 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
507618 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
507633 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0
507650 INFO: wrote C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1\RBZapp.spec
507666 INFO: UPX is not available.
507681 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\classes\\python\\python']
507845 INFO: checking Analysis
507848 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-02.toc is non existent
507854 INFO: Reusing cached module dependency graph...
507961 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
508168 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-02.toc
508189 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
508244 INFO: Analyzing D:\classes\python\python\RBZapp.py
510710 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
510724 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
517384 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
519929 INFO: Processing module hooks...
519934 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-eel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
520020 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
520032 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
520054 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
520066 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
520077 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
520136 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\MY-WOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp49x5u3r1\RBZapp.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['D:/classes/python/python/RBZapp.py'],
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 445, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 606, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-gevent.py", line 16, in <module>
    datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 1081, in collect_all
    hiddenimports = collect_submodules(package_name, filter=filter_submodules)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 564, in collect_submodules
    names = exec_statement(
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 91, in exec_statement
    return __exec_statement(statement, capture_stdout=True)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 75, in __exec_statement
    return __exec_python_cmd(cmd, capture_stdout=capture_stdout)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 66, in __exec_python_cmd
    txt = compat.exec_python(*cmd, env=pp_env)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 546, in exec_python
    return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 332, in exec_command
    out = proc.communicate(timeout=60)[0]
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1149, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1525, in _communicate
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, orig_timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '('C:\\Users\\my-work-laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-c', '\nimport sys\nimport pkgutil\nimport traceback\n\n# ``pkgutil.walk_packages`` does not walk subpackages of zipped files per https://bugs.python.org/issue14209.\n# This is a workaround.\ndef walk_packages(path=None, prefix=\'\', onerror=None):\n    def seen(p, m={}):\n        if p in m:\n            return True\n        m[p] = True\n\n    for importer, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(path, prefix):\n        if not name.startswith(prefix):\n            name = prefix + name\n        yield importer, name, ispkg\n\n        if ispkg:\n            try:\n                __import__(name)\n            except ImportError:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n            except Exception:\n                if onerror is not None:\n                    onerror(name)\n                else:\n                    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)\n                    print("collect_submodules: failed to import %r!" % name, file=sys.stderr)\n            else:\n                path = getattr(sys.modules[name], \'__path__\', None) or []\n\n                # don\'t traverse path items we\'ve seen before\n                path = [p for p in path if not seen(p)]\n\n                # Use Py2 code here. It still works in Py3.\n                for item in walk_packages(path, name+\'.\', onerror):\n                    yield item\n                # This is the original Py3 code.\n                #yield from walk_packages(path, name+\'.\', onerror)\n\nfor module_loader, name, ispkg in walk_packages([\'C:\\\\Users\\\\my-work-laptop\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Programs\\\\Python\\\\Python310\\\\lib\\\\site-packages\\\\gevent\'], \'gevent.\'):\n    print(\'\\n$_pyi:\' + name + \'*\')\n')' timed out after 60 seconds

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

When i try to run auto-py-to-exe in the environment i just created using python3.10, its also giving me problems, it doesn't open i get an error:

```
File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                            File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code                exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                               File "D:\classes\python\python\env\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>                         File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>                    from . import ui                                                                                                      File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 5, in <module>                           import eel                                                                                                            File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>                                import gevent as gvt                                                                                                  File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\gevent\__init__.py", line 86, in <module>                            from gevent._hub_local import get_hub                                                                                 File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\gevent\_hub_local.py", line 101, in <module>                         import_c_accel(globals(), 'gevent.__hub_local')                                                                       File "D:\classes\python\python\env\lib\site-packages\gevent\_util.py", line 148, in import_c_accel                        mod = importlib.import_module(cname)                                                                                  File "C:\Users\my-work-laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                                                                                                      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gevent._gevent_c_hub_local'
```

pip freeze shows gevent is installed. Please help

Comment: `python3.10` is ever new version so some modules may not be ready to work with this version. Better wait few months and use at least `3.9`.

Comment: I uninstalled 3.10 and installed 3.9.1 which is the version being used on the video im watching but im still getting the same error "TimeoutExpired" as before.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).